# How to store a reference to a class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, reference

So, I have this code:

```
int cols = 5, rows = 5;

class Node
{
public:
    Node()
    {
        this->x = 0;
        this->y = 0;
    }

    Node(int i, int j)
    {
        this->x = i;
        this->y = j;
    }

    void AddNeighbors(Node** grid)
    {
        if (this->x < cols - 1)
        {
            this->neighbors.push_back(grid[this->x + 1][this->y]);
        }
        if (this->x > 0)
        {
            this->neighbors.push_back(grid[this->x - 1][this->y]);
        }
        if (this->y < rows - 1)
        {
            this->neighbors.push_back(grid[this->x][this->y + 1]);
        }
        if (this->y > 0)
        {
            this->neighbors.push_back(grid[this->x][this->y - 1]);
        }
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    vector<Node> neighbors;

    bool operator == (Node n2) 
    {
        return this->x == n2.x && this->y == n2.y;
    }

    bool operator != (Node n2) 
    {
        return this->x != n2.x && this->y != n2.y;
    }
};

void RemoveFromVector(vector<Node> &nodesSet, Node element)
{
    vector<Node>::iterator it = nodesSet.begin();

    for (int i = nodesSet.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (nodesSet[i] == element)
        {
            advance(it, i);
            nodesSet.erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }
}

bool ExistsInVector(vector<Node>& nodesSet, Node element)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nodesSet.size(); i++)
    {
        if (nodesSet[i] == element)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Node** grid;

    grid = new Node* [cols];

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = new Node[rows];
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            Node node = Node(i, j);
            grid[i][j] = node;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j].AddNeighbors(grid);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a lot of problems when I have to store neighbors because they are not of a reference type. At some point of a program I have to accesses neighbors of a neighbors but they don't have neighbors :)

So, I know that I have to store neighbors as a reference but it will break mostly everything (for example I'll need to overload two functions: RemoveFromVector and ExistsInVector so they will have to get Node* element as a parameter). Maybe it is possible to create Node class as a reference but it won't break everything?

UPD: I have such questions because most of the programming time I've worked with Ruby where mostly everything is a reference and given code definitely will work in Ruby.

Comment: Use pointers... preferably smart pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself but it feels that this is the most non-C++ way to solve my problem:

```
int cols = 5, rows = 5;

class Node
{
public:
    Node() : x(0), y(0)
    {
    }

    Node(int i, int j) : x(i), y(j)
    {
    }

    void AddNeighbors(Node*** grid)
    {
        if (this->x < cols - 1)
        {
            this->neighbors.push_back(grid[this->x + 1][this->y]);
        }
        if (this->x > 0)
        {
            this->neighbors.push_back(grid[this->x - 1][this->y]);
        }
        if (this->y < rows - 1)
        {
            this->neighbors.push_back(grid[this->x][this->y + 1]);
        }
        if (this->y > 0)
        {
            this->neighbors.push_back(grid[this->x][this->y - 1]);
        }
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    vector<Node *> neighbors;

    bool operator == (Node const & n2) const
    {
        return this->x == n2.x && this->y == n2.y;
    }

    bool operator != (Node const & n2) const
    {
        return this->x != n2.x && this->y != n2.y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node*** grid;

    grid = new Node** [cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = new Node*[rows];        
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = new Node(i, j);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j]->AddNeighbors(grid);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally in c++, it is better to manipulate the container iterators instead of having references/pointers in each element. Instead of a member function node.getNext(), you can simply have ++nodeIt and then *nodeIt to access it. In your 2d matrix case, you have to develop your own iterator (see [custom iterator class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/)) in order to implement your increment functions in the 4 directions (and protect the border cases in the implementation). Once it is done, you can simply make these functions return the end iterator to be able to check if the advance didn't work.

If you really want the node.getRight/Left/Up/Down() pattern, you can store 4 pointers in each node (not proprietary, just raw pointers) and let them to nullptr to be able to check when there is not a next node in the desired direction.